# move tableview delegates to different class

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, xcode6

I have one **view controller** containing lots of operations. Most of the views are created **dynamically**. To separate out code I created a class as a `myClass` of `NSObject` where I created a function `showMyTableView`. This function adds a `tableview` as `subview`. but I have to write all `tableview delegates` inside `view controller`. How I can move require delegates to myclass?

Tomorrow I may require to add subview containing buttons for which I should write action in separate class.

How I can accomplish same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(By 'table view delegates', I assume you mean your table view's `delegate` and `dataSource`?)

You can certainly move this stuff to another class. You would simply set the `delegate`/`dataSource` of your table view to an instance of `MyClass`, in your view controller, like so:

```
self.tableView.delegate = instanceOfMyClass;
```

`MyClass` probably shouldn't be responsible for creating the table view and adding it to your view controller's view though. Your view controller should be responsible for this itself.

Answer (score 2):

your new class should handle data only, not ui.

for different table cellview consider use separate tableviewcell subclasses and provide them data models. let them configure themselves